# Line spacing in a block of text

Tags: line-height

Generally speaking, does there exist an "optimal" line height as a proportion of how high the text is, for maximum readability?

Comment: MS Word 2010 has a default of 1.5 lines, IIRC. I find it too much, though. It depends on the font. Fonts with large ascenders/desenders need a bit more line spacing.

Comment: The answer to this is more complex than it might appear. For a start, there is not a single measure of type height - there's the 'point size' or em (which is a relative unit, fixed only with respect to a given typeface), the cap height, the ascender height, the x-height, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.2 ems is standard accepted for best readability. Often it gets to be a bit bigger on websites.

http://kingdesk.com/articles/optimal-line-height/

longer lines of text can benefit from more spacing as well (easier to find the next line as you're reading)

Comment: There isn't a 'standard' as it depends on many other factors--namely the type style, the line length, the size of the type, etc. '1.2' is a safe start, but not a universal rule by any means.

Comment: definitely. I guess it depends how 'generally' we're speaking

Comment: Ha! True. Good point. "generally speaking" it's certainly a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the block text I personally use this simple rule:

> Vertical space between the lines (put in lowercase)  should be ca. 180%
> of the height of the lowercase letters.

To illustrate the rule, I copy paste the letter "o" and fit it between the lines:

[image]

So the optimal spacing IMO is when I can fit slightly less than two whole letters between the lines.

**However**, one should be aware of the fact that the number (line height) is not even related to the optical line height (lowercase height), but normally related to the so-called em-height, so it is better just to look at the actual result and adjust accordingly.